# How to use generic class with specific objects in a static context?

Tags: java, inheritance, static, playframework-2.0

I'm gonna try to explain at my best.

I use Play Framework 2, and I will do a lot of CRUD actions. Some of them will be identitcal, so I'd like to KISS and DRY so at first I was thinking about an abstract class containing the `list`, `details`, `create`, `update` and `delete` methods, with generic object, and extend this class by specifying which object to use (Model & Form) :

```
public abstract class CrudController extends Controller {
    protected static Model.Finder<Long, Model> finder = null;
    protected static Form<Model> form = null;

    public static Result list() {
        // some code here
    }

    public static Result details(Long id) {
        // some code here
    }

    public static Result create() {
        // some code here
    }

    public static Result update(Long id) {
        // some code here
    }

    public static Result delete(Long id) {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

And a class that will use CRUD :

```
public class Cities extends CrudController {
    protected static Model.Finder<Long, City> finder = City.find;
    protected static Form<City> form = form(City.class);

    // I can override a method in order to change it's behavior :
    public static Result list() {
        // some different code here, like adding some where condition
    }
}
```

This would work if I wasn't in a static context.

But since it's the case, how can I do ?

Comment: Why not simply switch to instance methods? Inheritance doesn't work on class methods in Java.

Comment: Another idea could be to replace inheritance with composition: just have CrudController's instances and delegate the operations to instance-specific contained object. (This all depends on your design, of course.)

Comment: @Vlad : For the first question, I can't, Play require static method for the controller. Now for the second, I'm not sure to understand, could you elaborate (or create a new answer)?

Comment: I'll put this into an answer.

Comment: @cx42net: I'm wondering.. You're trying to make your controller generic. But the list() method of Cities will return another view than the list() method of e.g. Users, won't it? How are you planning to make that generic?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be achieved using delegation: define a regular Java class containing the CRUD actions logic:

```java
public class Crud<T extends Model> {

    private final Model.Finder<Long, T> find;
    private final Form<T> form;

    public Crud(Model.Finder<Long, T> find, Form<T> form) {
        this.find = find;
        this.form = form;
    }

    public Result list() {
        return ok(Json.toJson(find.all()));
    }

    public Result create() {
        Form<T> createForm = form.bindFromRequest();
        if (createForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest();
        } else {
            createForm.get().save();
            return ok();
        }
    }

    public Result read(Long id) {
        T t = find.byId(id);
        if (t == null) {
            return notFound();
        }
        return ok(Json.toJson(t));
    }

    // … same for update and delete
}
```

Then you can define a Play controller having a static field containing an instance of `Crud<City>`:

```java
public class Cities extends Controller {
    public final static Crud<City> crud = new Crud<City>(City.find, form(City.class));
}
```

And you’re almost done: you just need to define the routes for the Crud actions:

```
GET     /                     controllers.Cities.crud.list()
POST    /                     controllers.Cities.crud.create()
GET     /:id                  controllers.Cities.crud.read(id: Long)
```

Note: this example produces JSON responses for brevety but it’s possible to render HTML templates. However, since Play 2 templates are statically typed you’ll need to pass all of them as parameters of the `Crud` class.

Comment: Imo returning the a view depending on the controller is the tricky part, how would you solve that?

Comment: That’s indeed an interesting problem. This question was more on how to reuse some logic despite the static nature of controllers (which disallow inheritance). Maybe you should open another question?

Comment: True, it's not really in the scope of this question. But was just wondering when reading your answer, which I like! Maybe I'll open another question tonight.

Comment: yes, please open up that question, would be really happy to know how to deal with templates in a generic way!

Comment: This idea does not work anymore for the play version 2.3 since the routes rules are more restrictive. Calling an action from an attribute of a Controller now throw an error. I asked for it on the mailing list : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/Pa8VkoyRJ2c/AqnDxnkQ5_YJ

Answer (score 4):

(Disclaimer: I have no experience with playframework.)

The following idea might help:

```
public interface IOpImplementation {
    public static Result list();
    public static Result details(Long id);
    public static Result create();
    public static Result update(Long id);
    public static Result delete(Long id);
}

public abstract class CrudController extends Controller {
    protected static Model.Finder<Long, Model> finder = null;
    protected static Form<Model> form = null;

    protected static IOpImplementation impl;

    public static Result list() {
        return impl.list();
    }

    public static Result details(Long id) {
        return impl.details(id);
    }
    // other operations defined the same way
}

public class Cities extends CrudController {

    public static Cities() {
        impl = new CitiesImpl();
    }

}
```

This way you can create a hierarchy of implementations.

(This must be some fancy-named design pattern, but I don't know the name ATM.)

Comment: There is some nice idea behind your answer, but what I'm looking for, is having a class by Model to modify in the database (cities, etc). Because when I define the routes, I need to point them to a specific class (controller). This controller will define which model to use. So it's not a problem if CrudController change, I just need to write as little code as possible for each Crud controller for the case the code is identical between various classes.

Comment: @cx42net: I didn't understand the part "having a class by Model". Does this mean that for each possible `Model` there should be one class derived from `CrudController` (or perhaps one instance of `CrudController`)?

Comment: Oh, this wouldn't work, as there are no instances. Wait, I'll update it.

Comment: `CrudController` would be generic by having no `Model`, and yes, for each derived class would be affected a Model, like the `Cities` controller would use the `City` `Model`. And for example, in `Cities`, all the methods are the same so I don't rewrite them, but for, say, `Users`, since it's more complexe, I would rewrite `list()` and `details()`. Is it more clear (I'm sorry if it's not :/).

Comment: @cx42net: Look at the updated code, this should suit the requirement "when I define the routes, I need to point them to a specific class (controller)" better.