# When using a generic controller, how to return a view inherent to a specific controller?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

As a result of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10708026/694597, I am wondering how to return a view inherent to a specific controller when using a generic controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you render a view in a controller action, you just invoke a plain function which has been generated by the template engine:

```java
public Application extends Controller {
  public static Result index() {
    return ok(views.html.index.render(42));
  }
}
```

Here, `render` is a method of the object `index` which has type `Template1<Integer, Html>`.

Now the question is: how to write a generic controller able to invoke a view specific to another controller? Or simply: **how to abstract over views**?

I see two solutions: **[inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)** and **reflection**.

Let’s see how to implement both on a simple use case. Say you have the following generic `Shower<T>` class able to compute an HTTP response containing an HTML representation of any value of type `T`:

```java
public class Shower<T> {
  public Result show(T value) {
    // TODO return an HTML representation of `value`
  }
}
```

## Inversion of control

To implement `Shower<T>` using inversion of control we just need to inject the `Template1<T, Html>` value used to perform the rendering:

```java
public class Shower<T> {

  public final Template1<T, Html> template;

  public Shower(Template1<T, Html> template) {
    this.template = template;
  }

  public Result show(T value) {
    return ok(template.render(value));
  }

}
```

To use it in a controller, create a static instance of `Shower<T>` and inject it the template to use:

```java
public class Application extends Controller {
  public static Shower<Foo> foo = new Shower<Foo>(views.html.Foo.show.ref());
}
```

## Reflection

You may find it too boilerplate to have to inject explicitly the template to use for each instance of `Shower<T>`, so you may be tempted to retrieve it by reflection, based on a naming convention, e.g. to show a value of type `Foo`, just look for an object named `show` in the package `views.html.Foo`:

```java
public class Shower<T> {

  private final Class<T> clazz;

  public Shower(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public Result show(T value) throws Exception {
    Class<?> object = Play.application().classLoader().loadClass("views.html." + clazz.getSimpleName() + ".show$");
    Template1<T, Html> template = (Template1<T, Html>)object.getField("MODULE$").get(null);
    return ok(template.render(value));
  }
}
```

(that’s the way to access Scala objects using reflection)

You can use it as follows in a controller:

```java
public class Application extends Controller {
  public static Shower<Foo> foo = new Shower<Foo>(Foo.class);
}
```

## Pros and cons

The reflection-based solution requires **less boilerplate** on the call site, but the fact it relies on a naming convention makes it **more fragile**. Furthermore, this solution will only fail **at runtime** when it’ll fail, while the first solution will show you your missing templates **at compile time**. Last but not least, the reflection based solution may add some **performance overhead** due to the reflection.

Comment: `ref()`! oh, this knowledge is going to be extremely useful! Thanks a lot for explaining this!

Comment: I like your Inversion of control solution! But if you have multiple methods in your `Shower` you also have to pass multiple views. Would it be useful to also use the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for that problem? (see also: Bloch, J. _Effective Java_ -> Item 2)

Comment: Ah far as I understand, this pattern allows you to write more readable code on the call site, but still requires you to pass all the views.

Comment: Indeed, you still have to pass all the views. But you don't have to pass them all at once to the constructor.