# {play 2.3}Java generic action (without generic static method)

Tags: java, generics, playframework-2.0

I have many actions (ie: static method returning a Result type within a class extending Controller) which are pretty much the same in my app. It is about crud actions. I have bdd tables and for each table, I implement the following actions : list, new, update... The only thing that change is the type of the Model class associated with the table.

If only the type change, it is time to call for generic functions ! Problem is : there is no way to create generic static functions in java. So action can't be generic.

The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703310/how-to-use-generic-class-with-specific-objects-in-a-static-context) no longer work.
This feature is so important that it must have been implemented somewhere in play. An idea I already thought about :

***Action composition***

Action composition is a way to call a function before another. Since action are not static, it is theoricaly possible to create generic actions.

Problem 1 : how to pass generic Type through annotation ?

Problem 2 : I already use action composition to make sure a user is logged in. Since my login action is class scope and generic crud action will be method scope, the crud action will be processed before the login action and there is no way to reverse it.

***Conclusion***

This is very important because I will have 20+ tables and I want to copy past as few as possible.

Is there a way to implement generic action (ie: static) that can be reuse and overwrite as many time as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use the play2-crud plugin for play. You can find it [here](https://github.com/hakandilek/play2-crud).

The pro of this plugin :

- The route system. All the routes for create/update/delete/show for both views and rest (ajax) are automatically generated.
- Make it possible to have a MyController class, with action not static which can use generics, be herited and override ! That solve the problem explained in the question !
- The engine for the crud database communication are already created. Although I needed to tweak it for a better error management, it is still an usefull thing.
- Use of dao (data access object) which make it easy to add checking before an object will be save to the database.
- Auto generated forms for the crud froms. Usefull if you want make backend database management, but you'll have to redraw everything for the users.

Cons of this plugin :

- Not compatible with play 2.3 yet. A friend of mine made a pull request for an upgrade so I am using a 2.3 compatible version pusblished locally, but it is not official yet.
- Small community. Few documentation, no mail group, no forum, the only place to post question is the github issue section.
- Still have few bugs, and the author of the plugin is not very active at this time (but maybe he is in holidays yet).

To conclude I used it and I am happy with it, so give it a try !